# jquery file upload - input file value is never displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blueimp

I have a html file input box:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" data-url="/FilePage/Upload" />
<input id="up_btn" type="button" value="Upload" />
```

in the browser (repeatable in IE/FF and chrome) after clicking the browse button and selecting a file, no file name is displayed in the box.

I am using jquery file upload to do this, so I wonder if it is somehow interfering with the box.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            $("#up_btn").off('click').on('click', function () {
                data.submit();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT:

Bizarrely, changing the final line to )}; makes it work, but this is invalid syntax. Looks like it is something related to the Jquery.fileupload function

I am using the jquery file upload library ( https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Comment: Please upload a jsfiddle please

Comment: fileupload is no native jQuery function

Comment: It works just fine on the jsfiddle.

Comment: The line containing }, is also invalid syntax. You cannot have a trailing comma in an object. (Some browsers will accept and ignore it though.)

Comment: @jlh well spotted, I've fixed that but the issue still remains.

Comment: @HoschNok I'm using jquery file upload.